# How can I create a sequence vector with a loop?

Tags: r, loops

I need to create a vector (with a loop) which contains the first hundred elements of this numeric sequence (1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/16, 1/32,...). Hint: (1/2^1, 1/2^2, 1/2^3,...,1/2^100)

I've tried it like this, but instead a vector I get just a number

```
inter<-c()

for(i in 1:100){
  sec<-c(inter,(1/2^i))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to create a vector (**with a loop**)

```
sec <- NULL
for(i in 1:100){
  sec[i] <- (1/2^i)
}
```